# 16bit Float Multiplication in C

Tags: c, algorithm, floating-point, computer-science

I'm working on a small project, where I need float multiplication with 16bit floats (half precision). Unhappily, I'm facing some problems with the algorithm:

### Example Output

```
1 * 5 = 5
2 * 5 = 10
3 * 5 = 14.5
4 * 5 = 20
5 * 5 = 24.5

100 * 4 = 100
100 * 5 = 482
```

### The Source Code

```c
const int bits = 16;
const int exponent_length = 5;
const int fraction_length = 10;

const int bias = pow(2, exponent_length - 1) - 1;
const int exponent_mask = ((1 << 5) - 1) << fraction_length;
const int fraction_mask = (1 << fraction_length) - 1;
const int hidden_bit = (1 << 10);  // Was 1 << 11 before update 1

int float_mul(int f1, int f2) {
    int res_exp = 0;
    int res_frac = 0;
    int result = 0;

    int exp1 = (f1 & exponent_mask) >> fraction_length;
    int exp2 = (f2 & exponent_mask) >> fraction_length;
    int frac1 = (f1 & fraction_mask) | hidden_bit;
    int frac2 = (f2 & fraction_mask) | hidden_bit;

    // Add exponents
    res_exp = exp1 + exp2 - bias;  // Remove double bias

    // Multiply significants
    res_frac = frac1 * frac2;   // 11 bit * 11 bit → 22 bit!
    // Shift 22bit int right to fit into 10 bit
    if (highest_bit_pos(res_mant) == 21) {
        res_mant >>= 11;
        res_exp += 1;
    } else {
        res_mant >>= 10;
    }
    res_frac &= ~hidden_bit;    // Remove hidden bit

    // Construct float
    return (res_exp << bits - exponent_length - 1) | res_frac;
}
```

By the way: I'm storing the floats in ints, because I'll try to port this code to some kind of Assembler w/o float point operations later.

### The Question

Why does the code work for some values only? Did I forget some normalization or similar? Or does it work only by accident?

Disclaimer: I'm not a CompSci student, it's a leisure project ;)

## Update #1

Thanks to the comment by [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) I noticed one problem with the code: the `hidden_bit` flag was off by one (should be `1 << 10`). With that change, I don't get decimal places any more, but still some calculations are off (e.g. `3•3=20`). I assume, it's the `res_frac` shift as descibred in the answers.

## Update #2

The second problem with the code was indeed the `res_frac` shifting. After update #1 I got wrong results when having 22 bit results of `frac1 * frac2`. I've updated the code above with a the corrected shift statement. Thanks to all for every comment and answer! :)

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger (or add print statements) to trace the values of *all* intermediate variables for one of the inputs that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Do you ever get a correct answer without having at least one input a power of two? Is the error always loss of the least significant 1 in the result?

Comment: @Oli: Already did that, I removed the print statements in the listing above.

Comment: Ok, so which intermediate variable didn't match what you were expecting?

Comment: I have web page on [how to debug](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/debug). It is not about the mechanics of putting in print statements, but about how to pick print/debug actions and use them to find what is wrong.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I just noticed the result is wrong if both arguments are odd numbers (except "1").

Comment: It is also wrong for 100*5, which has an even input but not a power of two. And remember 1, although odd, is a power of two.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: You're right. I'm still investigating the pattern.

Comment: So it seems like only one input has to be not power of two, although it works sometimes: "8 * 7 = 56".

Comment: Consider replacing `int` with `uint16_t` and careful handling of `frac1 * frac2`.

Comment: When multiplying 3*5, frac1 * frac2 returns `10100010000000000000000`. This gets shifted and the first bit is removed, resulting in `1000100000`. The correct mantissa for `15` would be `1001000000`, so the error seems to happen at the multiplication or before...

Comment: @m--s: How do you figure 3•5 should have a significand of 1001000000? Integer three is 11, and its normalized significand is 11000000000 (with leading bit). Integer five is 101, and its normalized significand is 10100000000. Multiplying those produces 111100000000000000000. Normalizing that produces 11110000000.0000000000 (shifted ten bits). Rounding produces 11110000000. Removing the leading bit produces 1110000000.

Comment: Looks like fixed point to me

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Oh, uh, I confused 3•5 with 5•5. When multiplying 5•5, I get `10100010000000000000000` and so on.

Comment: As of Update #2 you are still not doing rounding right.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Yep, that's correct. As of update #2, I'm glad to have multiplication itself working, thus rounding of the result is something I will work on later (and maybe update the code above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a cursory look:

- No attempt is made to determine the location of the high bit in the product. Two 11-bit numbers, each their high bit set, may produce a 21- or 22-bit number. (Example with two-bit numbers: 10<sub>2</sub>•10<sub>2</sub> is 100<sub>2</sub>, three bits, but 11<sub>2</sub>•11<sub>2</sub> is 1001<sub>2</sub>, four bits.)
- The result is truncated instead of rounded.
- Signs are ignored.
- Subnormal numbers are not handled, on input or output.
- `11` is hardcoded as a shift amount in one place. This is likely incorrect; the correct amount will depend on how the significand is handled for normalization and rounding.
- In decoding, the exponent field is shifted right by `fraction_length`. In encoding, it is shifted left by `bits - exponent_length - 1`. To avoid bugs, the same expression should be used in both places.

From a more detailed look by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux):

- `res_frac = frac1 * frac2` fails if `int` is less than 23 bits (22 for the product and one for the sign).

Comment: Concerning the signs: I will work with positive numbers only, so I left out the signs.

Comment: Also `res_frac = frac1 * frac2;` dramatically fails if sizeof(int) == 2.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are truncating instead of rounding:

```
res_frac >>= 11;            // Shift 22bit int right to fit into 10 bit
```

You should compute `res_frac & 0x7ff` first, the part of the 22-bit result that your algorithm is about to discard, and compare it to `0x400`. If it is below, truncate. If it is above, round away from zero. If it is equal to `0x400`, round to the even alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a suggestion for how to make it easier to get your code right, rather than analysis of what is wrong with the existing code.

There are a number of steps that are common to some or all of the floating point arithmetic operations. I suggest extracting each into a function that can be written with focus on one issue, and tested separately. Then when you come to write e.g. multiplication, you only have to deal with the specifics of that operation.

All the operations will be easier working with a structure that has the actual signed exponent, and the full significand in a wider unsigned integer field. If you were dealing with signed numbers, it would also have a boolean for the sign bit.

Here are some sample operations that could be separate functions, at least until you get it working:

unpack: Take a 16 bit float and extract the exponent and significand into a struct.

pack: Undo unpack - deal with dropping the hidden bit, applying the bias the expoent, and combining them into a float.

normalize: Shift the significand and adjust the exponent to bring the most significant 1-bit to a specified bit position.

round: Apply your rounding rules to drop low significance bits. If you want to do IEEE 754 style round-to-nearest, you need a guard digit that is the most significant bit that will be dropped, and an additional bit indicating if there are any one bits of lower significance than the guard bit.